# JSON(list, not dictionary) to csv file - PYTHON

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to convert JSON file to csv, using python.

I tried the method of taking the data into dictionary however my JSON file is in lists hence it never works. It does not take string indices.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('RA_1.json', 'r') as f:
    data_dict = json.load(f)

for data in data_dict:
    print(data['result']['specific_issues']['bills_by_algo'] ['sponsor'])
```

"THIS IS MY JSON FILE:"

```
"result": [
    {
        "issue_codes": [
            "BUD",
            "EDU"
        ],
        "received": 1436367560,
        "has_amendments": false,
        "client_name": "Apple Inc",
        "period": "2nd Quarter (Apr 1 - June 30)",
        "registrant": "Bernstein Strategy Group",
        "amount": 20000,
        "client": {
            "legal_name": "Apple Inc",
            "name": "Apple, Inc.",
            "naics": "334111",
            "gvkey": "1690",
            "ticker": "AAPL",
            "id": null,
            "bvdid": "US942404110"
        },
        "specific_issues": [
            {
                "text": "HR 5 -- Student Success Act -- blended learning provision S. 1177 Every Child Achieves Act -- specifically seeking addition of educational technology program and amendments related to student privacy and homework gap Unintroduced House legislation to update the Federal Education Records Privacy Act HR 2092 -- Student Digital Privacy and Parental Rights Act of 2015 S. 1341 -- Student Privacy Protection Act S. 1322 -- Protecting Student Privacy Act Unintroduced House and Senate legislation to address the homework gap Unintroduced Senate student privacy legislation \n",
                "bills_by_algo": [
```

"and more"

"This is the error:"

```
--------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c3b4246762f8> in <module>
      6 
      7 for data in data_dict:
----> 8     print(data['result']['specific_issues']['bills_by_algo']['sponsor'])

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because `specific_issues` is a list of dictionaries! Same issue with `bills_by_algo`

You must update your looping code to iterate through that list of dictionaries and find the keys within those individual dicts.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('RA_1.json', 'r') as f:
    data_dict = json.load(f)

    for data in data_dict['result']:
        specific_issues = data['specific_issues']

        for issue in specific_issues:
            print(issue['bills_by_algo'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`for data in data_dict` is wrong for your use. When you iterate from a dict, you get its keys, while you do not use its `items()` method. Here you got the string "result" in `data` *only* (*I suppose it since you do not give the end of the file*).

So, remove the `for` instruction and only write :

```
print(data_dict['result']['specific_issues']['bills_by_algo']['sponsor'])
```